# Configure IBM Websphere Liberty Profile Server Start & Stop timeout values outside of Eclipse

Tags: websphere-liberty

I am developing applications running on the Liberty Profile

```
(WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.7/wlp-1.0.10.cl50720150827-0437) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.7.0_71-b14 (en_GB)
```

I have had to increase the Server Startup Timeout value within eclipse to 300s.

Once I have completed my developmemt and want to deploy to a "stand alone" Liberty Server, e.g. Outside of Eclipse. How do I configure this Server Startup timeout?

Comment: The Server startup timeout is how long eclipse will wait until it assumes a server has failed and it kills it. When outside of eclipse there is nothing there to kill it so there is no setting to apply. Perhaps I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Alasdair I would suggest just creating an answer.

Comment: @Alasdair I believe you are correct, this is an Eclipse setting NOT a Liberty configuration feature.

Comment: @Hector since Alasdair isn't posting an answer, I think it's fair game to post his response an answer and accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We do have a new configuration option for how long the server will wait for the applications to start. If your application takes a few minutes to start the server will no go up until all your applications are ready.

You can read about this here:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI51375

This configuration option can be used with:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI49508

That last one will close any connection that comes while the server is starting.

You could use both this configuration options to hold up the server start based on your application start up time. For shutdown there is nothing I can recommend.

Other than that, as @Alasdair has answered we do not have any start or shutdown timeout in the Liberty Server.

Another thing you can do for delaying the startup is creating a shell script or similar to sleep for x amount of time before starting the application server.