# Control Liberty http endpoint enablement

Tags: open-liberty

I have 2 war in my server. First starts very rapidly but the second one is longer to start.
My server is able to respond to REST calls when fast one is started but it seems that HTTP endpoint can only be accessed when both applications are started.
Is there a way to control this so that I can respond rapidely to REST calls with first application and let the second application startup in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check this [post - Configure IBM Websphere Liberty Profile Server Start & Stop timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34864017/3701228).

You can set `<applicationManager startTimeout="1m"/>` setting to tell server not to wait for applications that start longer than timeout. Be aware that any request that comes into an application that is not ready to serve requests will return a HTTP 404 response.